# Difference inside a TABLE

Tags: mysql, sql

I have some data like that :

[image]

I'm trying to only return with a `SELECT` the row with `DATA=MONITO` but without `DATA=SIGN` (when then VI and NUM are the same)

In this exemple, only the third row should be returned.

Comment: select * from table where DATA='MONITO' and VI=VUM

Comment: This won't work, i want the row where DATA=MONITO only if in the same table there is no row with the same VI and NUM and with DATA=SIGN

Answer (score 0):

I think you want something like this:

```
select t.*
from table t
where not exists (select 1
                  from table t2
                  where t2.subj_id = t.subj_id and
                        t2.num = t.num and
                        t2.data = 'MONITO'
                 );
```

Your question is unclear on which columns are actually used to exclude the second row.  I am guessing it is the first and third.  In any case, the `not exists` approach should be adaptable to whatever logic you actually need.

Answer (score 0):

TRY THIS

```
SELECT *
       FROM TEST
            WHERE VI*100 + NUM NOT IN 
                               (SELECT VI*100 + NUM 
                                FROM TEST
                                WHERE DATA ='SIGN')
            AND DATA = 'MONITO';
QUIT;
```

Gordon's answer is on the right track but as written returns the null set.

Rubix is right about the solution being data dependent but his solution also returns the null set

Comment: Interesting solution but I don't like that it is data-dependent. It is feasible to have multiple combinations of VI and NUM where VI*100 + NUM equals the same number.

Example: 
VI = 1 NUM = 1
VI = 0 NUM = 101

Of course if your structure doesn't allow this, you'd be safe using it. I just hate coding to my data, as you'll now have this arbitrary restriction imposed.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT *
FROM t
WHERE DATA="MONITO"
AND "SIGN" NOT IN (SELECT DATA FROM t as t2 WHERE t2.VI = t.VI AND t2.Num = t.num)
```

Answer (score 0):

and here's a solution that's not data dependent:

```
proc sql;
select * from test 
except

select distinct d.*
from test as d 
inner join

(select a.vi, a.num from (select * from  test where data = 'SIGN') as a
inner join
test as b
on a.vi = b.vi
and a.num=b.num)as c
on d.vi = c.vi
and d.num = c.num;
quit;
```